# Git says my branch is up-to-date after reinstalling Windows (and Git) while it's actually not up-to-date at all

Tags: git

Before reinstalling my system, I had lots to commit and wasn't sync with origin at all. After reinstalling Windows and Git, Git says it's all sync and there's nothing commit. What can I do to pull/merge origin's last version while being sure that my last local work will be kept (since I can't even commit it)?

Comment: You can just clone the repository to a different directory :-) It's the easiest and foolproof way I think.

Comment: Can I just check, when you say "lots to commit and wasn't in sync with origin at all", do you mean that (1) you had uncommitted work, locally, *and* (2) your local branch was out of sync with the remote branch (e.g. master not in sync with origin/master)? Or, do you just mean the second, that the local branch was out of sync with the remote?

Comment: Andrew: that won't keep my uncommited work. @GavinHope: yes both, uncommited work and no sync between local and remote branches. That's because between my last pull and my Windows reinstall I did some local changes.

Comment: What do you get when you run `git status`? Also, running `git fetch` would be a safe way to *fetch* from the remote with doing the implied `merge` that comes with the `pull`...

Comment: It just says that I'm up-to-date with origin, nothing else. Ok, what should I do after git fetch?